# LetsEncrypt challenges and SRV records

Tags: ssl, dns, xmpp, srv

The SRV record allows hosting a service for a specific domain (commonly XMPP) on a different host than the A/AAAA record indicates. However, from what I can read in the documentation, the host that provides a service must still have a certificate authorizing it for the original domain name.

So: Is there any good solution that would allow me to run a secure XMPP server and an HTTP server for the same domain on different machines?

As an example, consider this zone for `example.com`:

```
@ 10800 IN A 0.0.0.0
_xmpp-client._tcp 10800 IN SRV 5 0 5222 xmpp.example.com.
_xmpp-server._tcp 10800 IN SRV 5 0 5269 xmpp.example.com.
xmpp 10800 IN A 0.0.0.1
```

The server at 0.0.0.1 must have a certificate that authenticates it for the name `example.com`, but only 0.0.0.0 (as the A record for example.com) can acquire that certificate from LetsEncrypt.

Do I just... generate the certificate on 0.0.0.0 and then transfer it over the network each time? Or temporarily set the web server on 0.0.0.0 to forward the `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` requests to 0.0.0.1? Neither of these seems very robust or secure.

Are SRV records essentially unusable in the https-everywhere world?

Comment: Indeed, browsers do not take care of SRV records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah.

LetsEncrypt supports other challenges that don't rely on the A record; specifically a DNS challenge: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-acme-acme-01#section-7.5

This merely requires the XMPP server to have access to the DNS registrar's API to allow it to temporarily set a TXT record.

Comment: acme.sh (available at https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh) makes it easy to do DNS-based verifications.